# Gnome search box to search history

Tags: gnome

I am using Gnome 3.6 on Ubuntu 13.04.

Is there any way to search history/ bookmarks of Web (Gnome web browser) from the search box directly?

So, I can hit Windows, type askubuntu, will get askubuntu.com in the result and visit the website?

Answer (score 1):

The [Search Firefox Bookmarks](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/149/search-firefox-bookmarks-provider/) extension seems to be exactly what you're looking for ([github link](https://github.com/sciancio/searchfirefoxbookmarks)). Take a look at the screenshot from their webpage:

[image: search bookmarks picture]

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. But this only searches FF, not Web, the gnome browser. I use Web very often.

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware Gnome has its own browser.

Comment: give it a try. It is called epiphany-browser while installing or web when installed.